# Протокол для многопользовательской игры

Tags: c++, websocket, tcp, udp, протоколы

Добрый день,

проект - многопользовательская игра, расчитаная на множество игроков (до 100), наподобие agar.io и тд. Сервер на C++, интерфейс - JavaScript (всё происходит внутри браузера). Стоит вопрос, как реализовывать передачу данных.

Идеи :

- TCP - WebSocket
- UDP - разрабатывающийся "протокол" netcode.io (но ввиду того, что портируемость только на Windows, идея отброшена)

Уважаемые пользователи, может вы можете подсказать, как лучше сие реализовывать. А если уж WebSocket предлагаете, то какую библиотеку для него использовать в C++?

Comment: Для подобного рода игр в идеале использовать UDP (т.к. состояние мира постоянно меняется и предыдущее становится неактуальным). Напрямую работать с UDP браузеры пока не собираются (и вряд ли будут), поэтому можно попробовать использовать RTCDataChannel в WebRTC, с fallback на вебсокеты.

Comment: Посмотрите на boost::asio

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ну с протоколом вы уже определились в своем же вопросе.

**Как лучше "сие" реализовать:**

Для вас идеальный вариант (если это js клиент и c++ server и до 100 юзеров):

**Библиотека:** [socket.io](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io)

**Пример сервера на c++:** [c++ socket.io server](https://github.com/pnxs/socket.io-serverpp)

При правильном подходе и железе такой сервер выдержит не одну тысячу пользователей онлайн.

Comment: @Mike socket.io как раз для вебсокетов (с откатом на long-поллинг и другие методы, если вебсокеты недоступны в браузере).

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan любопытно, а зачем тогда в примере сервера применяется еще websocket++

Comment: @Mike В socket.io есть реализации клиентов/серверов для разных языков. Для сервера на плюсах, для работы с вебсокетами используется websocket++ (дабы не переизобретать велосипед вероятно).

Comment: Только надо заметить - количество пользователей весьма условно, т.к. зависит от железа, и железной архитектуры системы (кластер), ну и конечно от прямоты и сложности работы самого бекенда.

Comment: я сам использую socket.io на своих серверах и могу уверенно сказать, что даже на таком середнячке как 4 ядра 3.4гц с 8гб рам на ssd легко держит голоcовую связь между 1к онлайна. Сам сервер на java.

Answer (score 6):

Привет,
Вам подойдет [Poco](https://pocoproject.org/index.html). Там есть реализация WebSocket и JSON - очень удобно.

Для обеспечения хорошей скорости, желательно разбивать информацию на маленькие сообщения. Например, организовать связь между взаимосвязанными объектами на сервере и на странице, а WebSocket соединение использовать как роутер между ними.